# How to deploy VM through Terraform in Azure without Loadbalancer, availability set and without storage for boot diagnostic

Tags: azure, automation, terraform, virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

I have just started coding in Terraform and doing the basics. Every code that I find in any repo asks comes with deploying a VM in Azure with LoadBalance, Availability Set and Storage to enable Boot Diagnostic.

Is there any simple syntax to disabled them ?

I tried to add "disabled" in front of those resource but that didnt work.

Comment: please add relevant code which shows what you have already tried

Comment: Can you share the code which you have tried! @Azure Wizzard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to deploy VM through Terraform in Azure without Loadbalancer,availability set and without storage for boot diagnostic

I have created **Azure VM** using **Terraform** without **Loadbalancer**, **Availability Set** and without storage for **boot diagnostic**

**Terraform code:**

```
provider  "azurerm"  {
features  {}
}
resource  "azurerm_resource_group"  "venkatrg"  {
name = "Venkat-resource-group"
location = "East US"
}
resource  "azurerm_virtual_network"  "vnet"  {
name = "venkat-vnet"
address_space = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
location = azurerm_resource_group.venkatrg.location
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.venkatrg.name
}
resource  "azurerm_subnet"  "subnet"  {
name = "vm-subnet"
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.venkatrg.name
virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
address_prefixes = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}
resource  "azurerm_network_interface"  "samplenic"  {
name = "VM-nic"
location = azurerm_resource_group.venkatrg.location
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.venkatrg.name
ip_configuration  {
name = "internal"
subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
}
}
resource  "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine"  "myvm"  {
name = "venkat-vm"
location = azurerm_resource_group.venkatrg.location
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.venkatrg.name
network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.samplenic.id]
size = "Standard_B1ls"
admin_username = "Venkat"
admin_password = "Password1234!"
os_disk  {
name = "VM-osdisk"
caching = "ReadWrite"
storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
}
source_image_reference  {
publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
offer = "WindowsServer"
sku = "2019-Datacenter"
version = "latest"
}
}
```

**Terraform apply:**

[image]

Once ran the above code,**Azure VM** got created without **Availability Set** , **Boot diagnostic** and **LoadBalancer** successfully.

[image]

**Boot diagnostic**

To check the boot diagnostic is enabled in VM, you can follow the below steps.

**Azure Portal > Virtual Machines > Select your VM > Boot diagnostic**

[image]

To check the **Loadbalancer** is associated with **VM**, you can use the below command.

```
az network nic show-effective-route-table -g "Venkat-resource-group" -n "VM-nic" --query "value[].{Name:virtualMachine.name, LoadBalancer:ipConfigurations[].loadBalancerBackendAddressPools[].id}"
```

**Output**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try using the following code:

```
## Public_IP - VM1 NIC
    resource "azurerm_public_ip" "public_VM1" {
    name                = "public_VM1"
    resource_group_name = 
    location            = 
    allocation_method   = "Static"

    tags = {
    environment = "Migration-Lab"
    }
   }




## NIC VM1
   resource "azurerm_network_interface" "VM1" {
   name                = "VM1"
  location            = 
  resource_group_name = 

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "VM1"
    subnet_id                     = 
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = 
  }
}

## Create a Linux VM1 in VNET1
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "LinuxVM1" {
  name                = "LinuxVM1"
  resource_group_name = 
  location            = 
  size                = "Standard_B1ms"
  admin_username      = "azureuser"
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.VM1.id]
  computer_name                   = "LinuxVM1"
  disable_password_authentication = true

 admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "azureuser"
    public_key = 
  }

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = var.ubuntu_version
    version   = "latest"
  }
}
```

filling the missing values.

It should be fine for a test environment

Cheers,
Nico

Comment: Thanks, I will have a go for this for a Linux VM.